# Kivy App Built with Buildozer: Your app currently targets API level 27 and must target at least API level 29

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I have created a released APK file for my App with buildozer and Kivy. Now when I am trying to release it on the Google Play Console, it gives me an error as below.

*Your app currently targets API level 27 and must target at least API level 29 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 29.*

I tried to change the buildozer spec file

```
android.api = 29
```

However, it does not solve the issue. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning everything and building again? Buildozer may erroneously be caching the old build with the old api.

Comment: Hi @inclement, thanks for the advice. I've changed it to android.api = 29, cleaned and rebuilt everything. Now it is working fine. Now I have another problem. After changing to android.api = 29, my kivymd file manager is not able to open "/storage/emulated/0" on my android device. Pretty odds..

Comment: I got the answer. Basically need to opt-out scoped storage as I am using Android 10 https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases